# ASP.Net Controls render same server reference multiple times

Tags: asp.net, reference, webforms, servercontrols

I have added a pager to the top and bottom of my custom `Table` server control in an inner child property namely `Footer` and `Header`

```
<twc:Table runat="server" DataSource="<%# Incidents %>" Pagination="<%# ui_twcPagerTableTop %>">
    <Header>
        <twc:Paginator runat="server" ID="ui_twcPagerTableTop" />
    </Header>
    <Columns>
        ...
    </Columns>
    <Footer>
        <twc:Paginator runat="server" ID="ui_twcPaginatorBottom" />
    </Footer>
</twc:Table>
```

Really I just want to add one Paginator and have it render on the page in multiple positions, using the same control reference on the server side (they are the same thing really).

e.g. Render `ui_twcPaginatorTableTop` in both the header and the footer.

Is there a way in markup to make a control render twice, in 2 separate locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this in javascript, copying the DOM elements and appending them to the Footer container. Works nicely - though it would be nice to have a server side solution.